# Unity3D Share Settings of an AudioSource

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine

I'm currently adding an AudioSource to every object that makes sound and having to manually adjust the Volume Rolloff. Is there any way I could set up the Volume Rolloff in one AudioSource and have all my AudioSources copy its settings in the script?

For example:

```
protected AudioSource audioSource;

void Awake () {
    audioSource = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
    audioSource.RollOff = SharedSettings.Instance.audioSource.RollOff;
}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with `prefabs`? Without knowing any details this sounds something where those could be used.

Comment: I'm still new but I do know prefabs. All the objects that make sound need to have an AudioSource Component and I'm currently manually changing the Volume Rolloff. I was just hoping there was a way to copy the Rolloff from one source onto another.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Copy Component` and then `Paste Component Values` to copy **all** the settings from `AudioSource` component.

Comment: this should be a comment